# Is it okay to save date format data to string format in mongodb for period searching?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have curiosity about is it okay to save date format data to string format for searching data using gte and lte?
The document fields consisted of string format (the data is inserted by using python isoformat).

**[Documents]**

[image: table fields]

When I typed the filter condition like below. It successfully works. I don't know why gte and lte works in string. Honestly, I thought that gte and lte can be used for searching date type data.

**[Search filter and result]**

[image]

Comment: `$gte` and `$lte` can be used for searching `date` or `number` or `string` type data. In your case might work but it's better to set date field as `date` type.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, its just doing string comparison.

Right now its working for you because you are currently comparing dates in same timezone.

While `2022-05-18T04:51:57-07:00` and `2022-05-18T11:51:57.000Z` are same, you wont be able to find `2022-05-18T04:51:57-07:00` using the query `{ insert_date:"2022-05-18T11:51:57.000Z" }`.

Even for `$gte` and `$lte`, while `2022-05-18T04:51:57-07:00` is 2 hours ahead of `2022-05-18T09:51:57.000Z`, it will still `2022-05-18T09:51:57.000Z` is greater because `9` is greater than `4`.

Now this is just a guess, but I think queries will definitely work faster if you actually store the date as date data type rather than string. I believe indexes will also perform better.

Sorting will definitely work faster if you store it as date instead of string.